# (HTTP) Hide page extension in the URL

Tags: html, apache, http, raspberry-pi, lan

I'm making a web page using my Raspberry PI and Apache. I made the page chat.html.
To connect to it I have to write in Chrome "http://192.168.1.39/chat.php". How can I hide the '.php'(or anything else) from page URL, so when I connect to "http://192.168.1.39/chat" directly it doesn't give Error 404?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use url rewriting for that. When using Apache, this can be done by editing a file called `.htaccess`. See http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 1):

Use URL rewriting by utilizing `.htaccess`. Basically `.htaccess` is a file that let's you alter the config of a webserver like Apache.

In your web site root, create a filed called `.htaccess`.

Paste this in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

*.php files can now be accessed the way you describe. For more info on htaccess and url rewriting, please reference http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: The website root is for example /var/www?

Comment: I can't put the file in beacuse when I create it, something automatic delete it

Comment: I don't think it is deleted. I think it is hidden because by default a lot of files starting with a dot are hidden by the system. I suggest you try making a file called htaccess, put above code in it and then rename it to .htaccess (just a workaround). /var/www could be your website root.